# DropdownList using Jquery for each not working on change function for the first time

Tags: jquery

```
<select id="ddlValidationList1">  
<option value="A">A</option>
<option value="B">B</option>
<option value="C">C</option>
</select>

<select id="ddlValidationList2">    
</select>

$('#ddlValidationList1').bind('paste cut change keyup', function (e) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var ddlValidationList = $('#ddlValidationList2');            
                ddlValidationList.append(
                $('<option></option>').html("EmailAddress")
                );
    }, 100);
    $("#ddlValidationList2 option").each(function () {
        alert("hello");            
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8V8RN/2/)

`"ddlValidationList2"` `foreach` function not working when `"ddlValidationList1"` on change function performed for the first time.

Comment: ignore ][1] at the end of jquery

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8V8RN/2/

Comment: You are not getting alert first time because `ddlValidationList2` has no option child initially. and `setTimeout` is executing in separate thread.

Comment: It worked fine on the jsfiddle for me. What do you mean first time?

Comment: run it for the first time, select any value from dropdown1 the alert will not be fired for the firstime, where as when we select dropdown value for the second time it fires

Comment: @Satpal: what could be the possible solution to overcome it

Comment: Move each in setTimeout http://jsfiddle.net/8V8RN/3/ **OR** simply remove setTimeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your setTimeOut function cause this.here an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/semir/PJ46r/) :

```
$('#ddlValidationList1').bind('paste cut change keyup', function (e) {

            var ddlValidationList = $('#ddlValidationList2');            
                    ddlValidationList.append(
                    $('<option></option>').html("Hi")
                    );

        $("#ddlValidationList2 option").each(function () {
            alert("hello");            
        });
    });
```